# What is the concise way to explain Prototype Inheritance (JavaScript) vs Classical Inheritance (Java, C++)?

Tags: inheritance, prototype-programming

What is the concise way to explain Prototype Inheritance (JavaScript) vs Classical Inheritance (Java, C++)? Also, do you have any good analogies to this?

Answer (score 1):

Over simplified analogy: clones VS cookies.

Prototypal Inheritance: Clones use templates.  Each new clone is cloned from the template.  Likewise, objects (clones) in JavaScript are cloned from the prototype object (template).

Classical Inheritance: Cookies use cookie cutters.  Each new cookie is based on the same cookie cutter and is unique.  In Java, C++ etc, the object (cookie) is determined by the class (cookie cutter).